# How to say "He went to bed without taking a shower, brushing his teeth, removing his contact lenses"?

Tags: grammar, negation, coordination

I want to say

> He went to bed without taking a shower, brushing his teeth, removing his contact lenses.

Do I have to repeat the negation for every verb as follows?

> 彼は、シャワーを浴びず、歯を磨かず、コンタクトレンズを外さず、寝てしまった。

Comment: Is it not: "... without taking **a** shower, brushing **his** teeth, removing **his** contact lens**es**". (I am just asking because I find it weird and since I do not speak English that well I would be please to have a confirmation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He went to sleep without showering or taking off his glasses.
　　グーグル翻訳→　　彼はシャワーや彼の眼鏡を離陸せずに寝てしまいました。※
　　ニンゲン添削→　　彼はシャワーも眼‌​鏡を外す事もせずに寝てしまいました。

△　彼は、シャワーも、歯磨きも、コンタクトレンズを外す事もせずに寝てしまった。

△　彼は、シャワーも、歯磨きも、コンタクトレンズを外す事さえもせずに寝てしまった。

○　彼は、シャワーも歯磨きもせず、コンタクトレンズも外さずに寝てしまった。

○　彼は、シャワーも歯磨きもせず、コンタクトレンズも付けたまま寝てしまった。
○　彼は、シャワーも歯磨きもせず、コンタクトレンズも付けたままで寝てしまった。

※　プロ翻訳者からの「グーグル翻訳」の講評：　　「離陸せずに」　を見て微笑んでしまうが、「寝てしまいました。」　の正確さ、完璧さがどこから来るのが分からず（ブラックボックス、アルファ碁）、正直言って恐怖を感じる。

Comment: could you say it using て、くて、で, etc? Like a compound sentence

Comment: シャワーも歯磨きもしないで、コンタクトレンズをして寝てしまった。　This may be shorter and better all around.

Comment: I upvoted, but you can't necessarily make yourself understood with symbols like ○ △ without notation.

Comment: @user4092:  We more-or-less have a convention to use on this site.  This answer corresponds with that convention (whether intentional or not).  See [Should we have a standard notation for example sentences?](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/169/78) on meta.